# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#form_reg').validate({
        rules:{
                "reg_name":{
                    required:true,
                    minlength:2,
                    maxlength:15

                },
                "reg_email":{
                    required:true,
                    email:true,
                    remote: {
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/reg/check_login.php"                                        


                    }                                        
                },
                  "reg_pass":{ 
                  required:true, 
                  minlength:7, 
                  maxlength:20

            }
        },

               messages:{
                "reg_name":{
                    required:"Вы не указали ваше Имя!",
                    minlength:"От 2 до 15 символов",
                    maxlength:"От 2 до 15 символов"
                },
                 "reg_email":{                ,
                  remote: "Этот email уже используется другим пользователем",
                  required:"Вы не указали ваш E-mail!",
                  email:"Не корректный E-mail"  
                },
                "reg_pass":{ 
                 required:"Вы не указали пароль!", 
                 minlength:"От 7 до 20 символов!", 
                 maxlength:"От 7 до 20 символов!" 
                }
               },
               submitHandler: function(form){
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    success: function(data) {

                        if (data == 'true' )
                        {
                            $("#block-form-registration").fadeOut(300,function(){

                                $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_good").fadeIn(400).html("Вы успешно зарегестрированы");
                                $("#form_submit").hide();
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_error").fadeIn(400).html(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
                );
               }

        });
    }
    );


  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ненужная запятая в строке `"reg_email":{                ,`